# Как решить вопрос с обработкой форм по пунктам?

Tags: php

Задача: 
1 Создайте форму с method=”post”.

2 В форме должны быть текстовая область (textarea) и кнопка.

3 В обработчике необходимо принять строку из текстовой области.

4 Создайте массив, где каждый элемент будет содержать 1 символ из переданной строки.

5 Удалите каждый чётный элемент (то есть 0, 2, 4 и так далее).

6 Соедините все элементы получившегося массива в одну строку и выведите её.
Примечание: Должно получиться что-то наподобие этого: пришла строка «Моя строка», а выйти в браузер должно: «о тоа».

Начало, вроде ясно как:

```html
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
    <textarea name="text" value="<?=$text?>"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>
```

```js
  <?php $text = false;
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $text = htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']);
        for ($i = 0; $i <strlen($text); $i++) {
            $arr[] = $i;
        }
       // echo $arr;
    }
 
 
/*   5 п "Удалите каждый чётный элемент (то есть 0, 2, 4 и так далее)."  C помощью чего это делается? Вот есть array-filter
ну ок.  но он разве удаляет элементы?  В мануале сказано,  что при обработке массива функцией array_filter() его нельзя изменять: добавлять, удалять элементы или обнулять массив, т.к. это может привести к некорректной работе функции.
И в форме нельзя написать что-то другое, чтобы также вывело. */
 
$array1 = array ("м"=>1, "о"=>2, "я"=>3, "с"=>4, "т"=>5, "р"=>6, "о"=>7, "к"=>8, "а"=>9,);
 
echo "Нечетные :n";
   echo '<br>';
 
print_r(array_filter($array1, "odd"));
 
   //6
echo '<br>';
   $arr = array ($text);
 
$comma_separated = implode(",", $arr);
 
 
echo $comma_separated; 
 
// Пустая строка при использовании пустого массива:
var_dump(implode('hello', array())); // string(0) ""
   echo '<br>';
 
 
echo mb_strlen($text, 'utf-8');
   echo '<br>';
 
 
print_r ($arr);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$text = 'Моя строка';

// Занесем в массив каждый символ
$chars = preg_split('//u', $text, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

foreach ($chars as $k => $v) {
    if($k%2==0) {
        unset($chars[$k]);
    }
}

$result = implode("", $chars);

var_dump($chars);
```

Comment: в форме в браузере, если записать "моя строка" - выводит ромбы, а если "my string" -`Array ( [0] => m [1] => y [2] => [3] => s [4] => t [5] => r [6] => i [7] => n [8] => g )'   а должно выводить "о тоа". и почему в 1 строке у вас в пост занесено `text`- это типа п.3? почему не `submit`?

Comment: Вам кинули пример как разбить строки на массив и как работать с четными числами массива. Неужели так трудно взять и изменить пару строк с учетом того что ваше первое сообщение и так тупо было скопировано с сети а значит сами вы даже думать не захотели над своей задачей а решили чтобы это сделали за вас другие.

Comment: с чего вы взяли, что оно скопировано? может быть это вы скопировали и тупо кинули? тогда ясно все.

Comment: @ VikiMayson как строки разбивать на массив мне и так известно. вопрос не об этом.

Comment: Потому что "найди 10 отличий" http://www.cyberforum.ru/php-beginners/thread2253554.html#post12426454 Дополнил. Надеюсь дальше догадаетесь сами как это сделать для вашей задачи?

Comment: @ VikiMayson О вы нашли мой вопрос с киберфорума даже..и дальше что? вы хотите сказать, что и там код откуда-то взят? мда..жаль тут мемов нет рукалицо

Comment: Потому что как минимум то, что вам и там и здесь уже дали ответы, но вы вообще не хотите думать как с ними работать, а ждете все готовое чтобы просто взять и копипастом вставить. Ответ дан, не разводите флуд.

Comment: Флуд это вы здесь разводите и только. Я думаю над этой задачей уже несколько дней! Решения мне никто не давал готового и я не жду. Если ничего ответить, кроме кидать мне примеры откуда-то, не отвечайте!  Умников и без вас полно здесь. Ваш ответ- мимо.